# Generate regular expressions for matching natural numbers between `m` and `n`

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

The type of regular expression is PCRE.

Write a program that output a valid PCRE such that it matches all natural numbers between `m` and `n` and does not match anything else. No leading zeros are allowed.

For example, let `m` and `n` be `123` and `4321`, then the program might output
`1(2[3-9]|[3-9]\d)|[2-9]\d\d|[123]\d\d\d|4([012]\d\d|3([01]\d|2[01]))`.

This matches the exact string, so `^` and `$` anchors are implicit.

One should try to balance the two:

1. The regular expression should have a reasonable size.
2. The code should be short.

Let's optimize for

`code length in characters` + 2*`regular expression length for input 123456 and 7654321`

Side Note: It be interesting if we can prove the shortest PCRE regular expression is of the size O(log n log log n) or something.

Comment: Can you define the winning criteria? Maybe something like `re_size*5 + prog_size` (smaller = better), where `re_size` is the maximum for `m` and `n` up to 5 digits. There are many other ways to do it - what matters is that we can grade the answers.

Comment: *"Write a program that output a valid PCRE such that it matches all natural numbers between m and n"* Presumably "and fails to match all other inputs", no? Lest some smart arse offers `print .*` in some language.

Comment: Would've been more fun with negative numbers :-D

Comment: `if(min == 123456 && max == 7654321){print_hardcoded_regex}else{enumerate_range_and_join}`

Answer (score 7):

## Perl, score 455

**191 chars, 132 regex length**

```
sub b{my$a=shift;$_=(@_>0&&$a.b(@_).($a-->0&&'|')).($a>=0&&($a>1
?"[0-$a]":$a));/\|/?"($_)":$_}sub a{b(@a=split//,<>-1+$x++).(@a>
1&&"|.{1,$#a}")}print'(?!0|('.a.')$)(?=('.a.'$))^\d{1,'.@a.'}$'
```

Input: `123456, 7654321`

```
(?!0|((1(2(3(4(5[0-5]|[0-4])|[0-3])|[0-2])|1)|0)|.{1,5})$)(?=((7(6(5(4(3(21|1)|[0-2])|[0-3])|[0-4])|[0-5])|[0-6])|.{1,6}$))^\d{1,7}$
```

**Update:** I was able to further simplify this when I realized that most of the patterns ended with things like `\d{3}`.  These were doing nothing more than enforcing a string length--and doing so very repetitively, since they occurred on every term.  I eliminated this by using another lookahead to enforce the "less than" condition, only checking that either: 1) the first part of the number does not exceed the input or 2) the number is fewer digits than the input.  Then the main regex just verifies that it is not too many digits.

I also incorporated Peter Taylor's idea of negative look-ahead for checking the "greater than" condition.

The key to simplifying this problem (at least for me) was to break the regex in two: a look-ahead makes sure the number is not less than the minimum, then the main part of the regex checks that it is not greater than the maximum.  It is a little bit silly for small input, but it is not so bad for large input.

Note: the `0|` at the beginning is to exclude anything that starts with a zero from matching.  This is required because of the recursive nature of the regex function: inner parts of the match can start with zero, but the entire number cannot.  The regex function can't tell the difference, so I excluded any number starting with zero as a special case.

Input: `1, 4`

```
(?!0|(0)$)(?=([0-4]$))^\d{1,1}$
```

Unreasonably Long Regex Version, 29 chars:

```
print'^',join('|',<>..<>),'$'
```

Comment: Don't forget that there's a special special case, which is that if `m` is 0 then you need to allow 0 despite it having a leading zero.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I thought "natural numbers" meant positive integers.  Checking wikipedia, I see that there is actually no agreement on whether zero is a natural number.  At this point, I choose to take refuge in the ambiguity rather than change my solution :)

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript, score 118740839

```
function makere(m,n){r='(';for(i=m;i<n;)r+=i+++'|';return (r+i)+')';}
```

I suppose whether or not you like this depends on how you define 'a reasonable size.' :-)

Comment: Not gonna test this. I believe you.

Answer (score 2):

**Haskell 2063+2*151=2365**

It's guaranteed the generated regex has length O(log n log log n).

`matchIntRange 12345 7654321`

`1(2(3(4(5[6-9]|[6-9]\d)|[5-9]\d\d)|[4-9]\d{3})|[3-9]\d{4})|[2-9]\d{5}|[1-6]\d{6}|7([0-5]\d{5}|6([0-4]\d{4}|5([0-3]\d{3}|4([012]\d\d|3([01]\d|2[01])))))`

```
import Data.Digits

data RegEx = Range Int Int | MatchNone | All Int
            | Or RegEx RegEx | Concat [RegEx] 

alphabet = "\\d"

instance Show RegEx where
  show (Range i j)
   | i == j    = show i
   | i+1 == j  = concat ["[",show i,show j,"]"]
   | i+2 == j  = concat ["[",show i,show (i+1), show (i+2),"]"]
   | otherwise = concat ["[",show i,"-",show j,"]"]
  show (Or a b)  = show a ++ "|" ++ show b
  show MatchNone = "^$"
  show (All n) 
   | n < 3     = concat $ replicate n alphabet
   | otherwise = concat [alphabet,"{",show n,"}"] 
  show e@(Concat xs) 
   | atomic e  = concatMap show xs
   | otherwise = concatMap show' xs
   where show' (Or a b) = "("++show (Or a b)++")"
         show' x = show x
         atomic (Concat xs) = all atomic xs
         atomic (Or _ _)    = False
         atomic _           = True

-- Match integers in a certain range
matchIntRange :: Int->Int->RegEx
matchIntRange a b
 | 0 > min a b = error "Negative input"
 | a > b       = MatchNone
 | otherwise = build (d a) (d b)
 where build :: [Int]->[Int]->RegEx
       build [] [] = Concat [] 
       build (a@(x:xs)) (b@(y:ys))
         | sl && x == y       = Concat [Range x x, build xs ys]
         | sl && all9 && all0 = Concat [Range x y, All n]
         | sl && all0         = Or (Concat [Range x (y-1), All n]) upper
         | sl && all9         = Or lower (Concat [Range (x+1) y, All n])
         | sl && x+1 <= y-1   = Or (Or lower middle) upper
         | sl                 = Or lower upper
         | otherwise          = Or (build a (nines la)) (build (1:zeros la) b)
         where (la,lb) = (length a, length b)
               sl      = la == lb
               n       = length xs
               upper   = Concat [Range y y, build (zeros n) ys]
               lower   = Concat [Range x x, build xs (nines n)]
               middle  = Concat [Range (x+1) (y-1), All n]
               all9    = all (==9) ys
               all0    = all (==0) xs
       zeros n   = replicate n 0
       nines n   = replicate n 9
       d 0 = [0]
       d n = digits 10 n
```

The code below is a simple version that helps with understanding the algorithm, but it doesn't do any optimization to improve the regex size.

`matchIntRange 123 4321`

```
(((1((2((3|[4-8])|9)|[3-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9))|[2-8]((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9)))|9((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9)))|((1((0((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9))|[1-8]((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9)))|9((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9)))|[2-3]((0((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9))|[1-8]((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9)))|9((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9))))|4((0((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9))|[1-2]((0((0|[1-8])|9)|[1-8]((0|[1-8])|9))|9((0|[1-8])|9)))|3((0((0|[1-8])|9)|1((0|[1-8])|9))|2(0|1)))))
```

The regular expression has 680 characters.
Here is the code

```
import Data.Digits

data RegEx = Range Int Int | MatchNone | Or RegEx RegEx | Concat [RegEx] 

alphabet = "\\d"

instance Show RegEx where
  show (Range i j)
   | i == j    = show i
   | otherwise = concat ["[",show i,"-",show j,"]"]
  show (Or a b)  = concat ["(",show a,"|",show b,")"]
  show MatchNone = "^$"
  show (Concat xs) = concatMap show xs

matchIntRange :: Int->Int->RegEx
matchIntRange a b
 | 0 > min a b = error "Negative input"
 | a > b       = MatchNone
 | otherwise = build (d a) (d b)
 where build :: [Int]->[Int]->RegEx
       build [] [] = Concat [] 
       build (a@(x:xs)) (b@(y:ys))
         | sl && x == y     = Concat [Range x x, build xs ys]
         | sl && x+1 <= y-1 = Or (Or lower middle) upper
         | sl               = Or lower upper
         | otherwise        = Or (build a (nines la)) (build (1:zeros la) b)
         where (la,lb) = (length a, length b)
               sl      = la == lb
               n       = length xs
               upper   = Concat [Range y y, build (zeros n) ys]
               lower   = Concat [Range x x, build xs (nines n)]
               middle  = Concat [Range (x+1) (y-1), build (zeros n) (nines n)]
       zeros n = replicate n 0
       nines n = replicate n 9
       d 0 = [0]
       d n = digits 10 n
```

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript (126 + 2*170 = 466)

```
~)]{`:&,:_,{:i'('\_(<:/i&=48-:D 2<{D^i!!D*|1,*}{'['\i>2D<'-'*D(']?'3$)<}if/D!!*{'\d{'/i>'1,'*_(i-'}|'D}*}%_')'*]}%'(?!'\~'$)'\
```

For the given values it [gives](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OzEyMzQ1NiA3NjU0MzIxCilde2A6Jiw6Xyx7OmknKCdcXyg8Oi9pJj00OC06RCAyPHtEXmkhIUQqfDEsKn17J1snXGk%2BMkQ8Jy0nKkQoJ10%2FJzMkKTx9aWYvRCEhKnsnXGR7Jy9pPicxLCcqXyhpLSd9fCdEfSp9JV8nKScqXX0lJyg%2FISdcfickKSdc)

```
(?!(\d{1,5}|1([01]\d{4}|2([0-2]\d{3}|3([0-3]\d{2}|4([0-4]\d{1}|5([0-5]))))))$)([1-6]?\d{1,6}|7([0-5]\d{5}|6([0-4]\d{4}|5([0-3]\d{3}|4([0-2]\d{2}|3([01]\d{1}|2([01])))))))
```

Dissection to follow, but the basic idea is to define a block of code which maps a single natural number to a regex matching any smaller natural number, and then turn the inputs `lb` and `ub` into a negative lookahead for (natural number smaller than `lb`) combined with the regex for (natural number smaller than `ub+1`).

The logic is quite complicated, so even by GolfScript standards it's cryptic. Until I get round to writing a detailed dissection, here's a list of variables:

```
&  the whole number string
i  the current idx
D  the current digit
/  not-the-last-digit
_  total number of digits
```

Comment: @dan1111, I looked at the documentation for PCRE but I didn't see anything forbidding out-of-order character classes, and the tester I used didn't give an error. I'll have to look into that. OTOH if your regex engine doesn't like an expression ending in `|` then that's a bug in your regex engine, not in my regex.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that `(a|)` is actually valid.  However, `[1-0]` in your previous regex did not work in Perl or an online tester I tried.

Comment: @dan1111, after you pointed it out I realised that the online tester I was using was swallowing the error. I reproduced it on a machine with Perl, and wrote a test framework using Perl to check the regexes. Thanks for pointing it out.